# Number of restricted partitions dominated by a certain one

Tags: polynomials, lattice-orders, integer-partitions

Once established a certain partition of n, I am interested in finding out which is the exact number of partitions with same amount of parts $l(\lambda)$ but that are dominated by the first one.

for a detailed description on dominance order recall this wikipedia entry:

[Dominance ordering on partitions of n.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominance_order)

So find a way to calculate $f_\lambda$ that:

$$f_\lambda = \#{\{\mu\in P ; l(\mu)=l(\lambda); \mu<\lambda \}}$$

Of course I expect to be related to $\lambda$'s components $\{\lambda_i\}$.
For instance a multivariate generating function (as depends on a general partition definition) or a recursive formula would represent a feasible answer to this question.

Partial answers for certain partition length would also be appreciated.

I have already found assuming base partition is $\lambda=\{\lambda_1\ge\lambda_2...\}$:

- If $l(\lambda)=1$ then $f_\lambda = |\lambda|=\lambda_1$
- If $l(\lambda)=2$ then $f_\lambda =
     \sum_{k=\lambda_2}^{\lfloor(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)/2\rfloor}{k}+\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)/2\rfloor}{k}=(2(\lfloor(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)/2\rfloor)^2-\lambda_2^2+(\lfloor(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)/2\rfloor))/2$

No further advance seems easy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was there a MSE you meant to link?  The link points to Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks saulspatz!